# Azure Synapse fastest way to process 20k statements in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, azure-synapse

I am designing an incremental update process for a cloud based database (Azure). The only existing changelog is a .txt file that records every insert, delete, and update statement that the database processes. There is no change data capture table available, or any database table that records changes and I cannot enable watermarking on the database. The .txt file is structured as follows:

```
update [table] set x = 'data' where y = 'data'
go
insert into [table] values (data)
go
delete from [table] where x = data
go
```

I have built my process to convert the .txt file into a table in the cloud as follows:

```
update_id | db_operation | statement                                       | user  | processed_flag
----------|--------------|-------------------------------------------------|-------|---------------
1         | 'update'     | 'update [table] set x = data where y = data'    | user1 | 0
2         | 'insert'     | 'insert into [table] values (data)'             | user2 | 0
3         | 'delete'     | 'delete from [table] where x = data'            | user3 | 1
```

I use this code to create a temporary table of the unprocessed transactions, and then loop over the table, create a sql statement and then execute that transaction.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_incremental_updates
WITH
( 
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [user] ),
    HEAP
)
AS
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Sequence, 
        [user],
        [statement]
FROM    upd.incremental_updates
WHERE   processed_flag = 0;

DECLARE @nbr_statements INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_incremental_updates),
        @i INT = 1;

WHILE   @i <= @nbr_statements
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_code NVARCHAR(4000) = (SELECT [statement] FROM temp_incremental_updates WHERE Sequence = @i);
    EXEC    sp_executesql @sql_code;
    SET     @i +=1;
END

DROP TABLE temp_incremental_updates;

UPDATE incremental_updates SET processed_flag = 1
```

This is taking a very long time, upwards of an hour. Is there a different way I can quickly processes multiple sql statements that need to occur in a specific order? Order is relevant because, for example: if I try to process a delete statement before the insert statement that created that data, azure synapse will throw an error.

Comment: Is it always single tables involved in the SQL statements, or multiple?

Comment: Each statement is for a single row in a single table. So: insert one row, delete one row, update one row. There are about 20k statements each day.

Comment: `begin tran;` beforehand and `commit tran;` after would speed it up a little. Your use case is not clear, do you have something generating these commands which need to be run, or is this just repeating transaction the same as another database. What about [transaction replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: There is an on-premises software application whose only change log is a text file of the transactions. Once I extract all of the initial data, I need to incrementally update by extracting the change log and processing the statements in the cloud. This is meant to scale in the future to multiple databases but I am doing proof of concept work right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less than 2 hours for 20k individual statements is pretty good for Synapse!

Synapse isn't meant to do transactional processing. You need to convert individual updates to batch updates and execute [statements like `MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for big batches or rows instead of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` for each row.

In your situation, you could:

- Group all inserts/updates by table name
- Create a temp table for each group. E.g. `table1_insert_updates`
- Run `MERGE` like statement from `table1_insert_updates` to `table1`.

For deletes:

- Group primary keys by table name
- Run one `DELETE FROM table1 where key in (primary keys)` per table.

Frankly 20k is such a bad number, it's not too small and far from big enough. So even after "grouping" you could still have performance issues if you batch/group sizes are too small.

Synapse isn't meant for transaction processing. It'll merge a table with a million rows into a table with a billion rows in less than 5 minutes using a single MERGE statement to upsert a million rows, but if you run 1000 delete and 1000 insert statements one after the other it'll probably take longer!

---

EDIT: You'll also have to use `PARTITION BY` and `RANK` (or `ROWNUMBER`) to de-duplicate in case there are multiple updates to same row in a single batch. Not easy depending on how your input is (update contains all columns (even unchanged) or only changed columns) this might become very complicated.

Again *Synapse is not meant for transaction processing.*

Comment: Right now, I am operating on a single database but I am going to scale to multiple databases. So 20k could easily become 500k with only 25 on-premises databases. I will look into the merge statements. My question about your process is: if I group all of the insert statements with all of the update statements, and then group all of the delete statements, does the ordering of the transaction matter? Could I end up deleting two rows when I should only be deleting one? I feel like the ordering of the transactions is important.

Comment: Would you recommend switching to Azure SQL database for faster transaction processing? Synapse is not a 100% requirement, it's just what I am using currently because it fits the cost structure well.

Comment: Very broad question, can't really say without asking a lot more questions on what your usecases are. In general SQL DW (AKA Synapse) is meant for MPP and DW (Data Warehouse) situations, so if you're dealing with reads/writes of millions and billions at a time then use it. If you have a million/billion individual insert/delete/updates then you want something like SQL Server/MySQL or Cosmos DB/Cassandra. I'll try and add some more general advise to answer if I get a chance. But otherwise I recommend you post a new question with details of what you're trying to achieve, feel free to tag me in it.

Comment: This has been very helpful and has given me a lot to think about. I will try what you posted above with the merge statements and spin up a SQL server in Azure to see if that runs faster. I am very new to Azure and in charge of the entire architecture so I am learning as I go.

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare a cursor for selecting all the data from temp_incremental_updates at once, instead of making multiple reads:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_incremental_updates
WITH
( 
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [user] ),
    HEAP
)
AS
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Sequence, 
        [user],
        [statement]
FROM    upd.incremental_updates
WHERE   processed_flag = 0;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT [statement] FROM temp_incremental_updates ORDER BY Sequence

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @sql_code
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql_code;
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @sql_code
END

-- Rest of the code
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Azure Synapse does not support cursors. The documentation says to replace cursors with while loops.

Comment: My bad, I thought you were working on ETL proccess previous upload to Synapse. Synapse is a data analytic tool, not meant for data transformation work, I suggest you a change in your approach.